# How to start a Treeview node edit with a key press

Tags: c#

Using VS2019 and C#, I am trying to trigger a treeview node edit when the user starts typing while the node is selected.

Using the KeyDown and KeyPress events I can check to see if the node is selected and begin the edit (if it's not already in edit mode),  but it's consuming the first key. So if someone types "Hello", it works but the node only gets "ello" as the "H" is getting consumed. Any thoughts?

```
private void treeview_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeview.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        if (treeview.SelectedNode.IsEditing) return;
        treeview.SelectedNode.BeginEdit());

    }
}
```

Comment: Always show the relevant code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the KeyPress event:

```
private void TreeView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null) {
    treeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
    SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I just figured out that would work and came back to see your post. Thanks.